# f is continuous on [0,1]. f(0) = f(1). Show that f'(1 - c) = f'(c)

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, rolles-theorem

Let $f$ be continuous on $[0,1]$ and differentiable in $(0,1)$ s.t. $f(0) = f(1)$. Prove that $\exists c \ where \ 0 < c < 1 \ s.t. \ f'(1 - c) = f'(c)$.

Here is my attempt

Since $f(0) = f(1)$, Rolle's Theorem applies.

This means $\exists c \in (0,1) \ s.t. \ f'(c) = 0$

Since $c \in (0,1)$, we can see that $1 - c \in (0,1)$.

To show this is also $0$, examine the original function.

If $0 = 1 - c$, then we see $c = 1$. This will satisfy the inequality giving us $f(0) = f(1)$.

If $1 = 1 - c$, then $c = 0$. This will also satisfy the inequality giving us $f(1) = f(0)$. So whether we use $c$ or $1 - c$, Rolle's Theorem will be satisfied at both points.

I was told this is incorrect, and I can see why. Where I try to show that $1 - c$ works as well, I am only given information about the function (f(0) = f(1)). Not the derivative. So I can see why this doesn't work. I was told as a hint to examine the function $g(x) = f(x) + f(1 - x)$. However, I am not so sure how to apply this to the problem and proceed. Can anyone give me some guidance?

Comment: Did you state the problem correctly? $f'(c) = f'(1-c)$ is always satisfied for $c = 1/2$.

Comment: Yes that is copied exactly from my problem set. That is how they gave it.

Comment: Then it does not make much sense. $c=1/2$ is a solution, and the condition $f(0) = f(1)$ is not needed at all.

Comment: Well, I copied it exactly, so maybe it was a typo on my instructor's part. I did double check though that is the exact problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$g(x)=f(1-x)+f(x)$, $g(0)=g(1)$ implies there exists $c$ such that $g'(c)=0$.

Comment: I think I see what he means though. If g'(c) = 0, then I can plug in and get g'(c) = 0 = f'(1 - c) - f'(c). Then, f'(1 - c) = f'(c). So I had the right idea with Rolle's Lemma, I think I just got surprised when he told me to use that function. I just didn't see it.

Comment: It is correct now, but as I mentioned above you can simply choose $c=1/2$, and the condition $f(0) = f(1)$ is not needed.

Comment: Wait, his correction has now confused me. If g'(c) = 0, we know have -f(x) = f(1 - x) which is not correct.

Comment: The derivative of $f(1-x)$ is $-f'(1-x)$ since $f(1-x)=f(h(x))$ where $h(x)=1-x$ and $(f(h(x))'=f'(h(x)).h'(x)=-f(1-x)$ since $h'(x)=-1$.

Comment: But now how does that imply g(0) = g(1) if it has +? You won't have f(1) - f(0) anymore. It will be f(1) + f(0), which need not be 0 if they are equal. Hmm. I see the second part now,  but that first part is a bit unclear.

Comment: $g(0)=f(1-0)+f(0)=f(1)+f(0)$ and $g(1)=f(1-1)+f(1)=f(0)+f(1)$. We deduce that $g(0)=g(1)$.

Comment: I see. Thank you!